# How to save animation position CSS3

Tags: css

Is it possible to save the position of an element in CSS3 after it has undergone a transformation? For example, let's say I had a block below:

`[x]`

and I moved it with `-webkit-transform:translateX(15px);`

```
           [x]
```

when the animation repeats it would go back to:

`[x]`

how can I make it so that when the animation repeats, it adds another `15px` to its new position?

```
                          [x]
```

Apologies if this question is confusing, I can try to clarify as best as I can if you ask.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with CSS, but you could use jQuery/JS to do this.

Comment: I think you can't do this **generally** with just CSS3, but you can predefine many @keyframes to achieve the same effect. Of course, the animation can't increase the step over and over (like as script code can do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with strictly CSS, however, this is quite simple with jQuery.

I defined a custom attribute `anims` on the div object that I increment every time it is clicked. When the div is clicked, that number+1 is multiplied by 15 and the div is animated to the right that amount. When the animation completes, the div is moved back to its starting point, ready to be clicked again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div#green").click(function(){
    
        var distance = 15 * (1+parseInt($(this).attr("anims")));
    
        $(this).animate({
            "margin-left": distance 
        }, 1000, function(){
        
            $(this).css("margin-left", "0").attr("anims", (1+parseInt($(this).attr("anims"))));
        
        });
    
    });

});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2av5v/)

---

### Edit:

If you'd rather do this with CSS transforms, that is possible too.

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div#green").click(function(){
    
        var distance = 15 * (1+parseInt($(this).attr("anims")));
    
        $(this).css({
            "-webkit-transform": "translateX("+distance+"px)",
            "-moz-transform": "translateX("+distance+"px)",
            "-ms-transform": "translateX("+distance+"px)",
            "-o-transform": "translateX("+distance+"px)",
            "transform": "translateX("+distance+"px)"
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
         
            $("div#green").css({
                "-webkit-transform": "translateX("+0+"px)",
                "-moz-transform": "translateX("+0+"px)",
                "-ms-transform": "translateX("+0+"px)",
                "-o-transform": "translateX("+0+"px)",
                "transform": "translateX("+0+"px)"
            }).attr("anims", (1+parseInt($("div#green").attr("anims"))));
        
        }, 1000);
    
    });
 
});
```

#### CSS:

```
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

### [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2av5v/3/)